# SLO calculation for 90% of requests under 1000ms

Tags: histogram, prometheus, percentile, rate

I'm trying to figure out the PromQL for an SLO for latency, where we want 90% of all requests to be served in 1000ms or less.
I can get the **90th percentile** of requests with this:

`histogram_quantile( 0.90, sum by (le) ( rate(MyMetric_Request_Duration_bucket{instance="foo"}[1h]) ) )`

And I can find what percentage of **ALL** requests were served in 1000ms or less with this.

`((sum(rate(MyMetric_Request_Duration_bucket{le="1000",instance="foo"}[1h]))) / (sum (rate(MyMetric_Request_Duration_count{instance="foo"}[1h])))) *100`

Is it possible to combine these into one query that tells me what percentage of requests in the 90th percentile were served in 1000ms or less?

I tried the most obvious (to me anyway) solution, but got no data back.

`histogram_quantile( 0.90, sum by (le) ( rate(MyMetric_Request_Duration_bucket{le="1000",instance="foo"}[1h]) ) )`

The goal is to get a measure that shows For the 90th percentile of requests, how many of those requests were under 1000ms?  Seems like this should be simple but I can't find a PromQL query that allows me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't provide a function, which could be used for calculating the share (aka the percentage) of requests served in under one second from  [histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) buckets. But such a function exists in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. The function is [histogram_share()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share). For example, the following query returns the share of requests with durations smaller than one second served during the last hour:

```
histogram_share(1s, sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[1h])) by (le))
```

Then the following query can be used for alerting when the share or requests, which are served in less than one second, drops below 90%:

```
histogram_share(1s, sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[1h])) by (le)) < 0.9
```

Please note that all the functions, which work over [histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) buckets, return the **estimated** results. Their accuracy highly depends on the used histogram buckets' boundaries. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the response Valyala.  This option still requires that we make changes to Sloth to modify the default output rules and unfortunately we are using Azure managed Prometheus and don't think VictoriaMetrics is an option for us.  
What we need is a measure for

- Taking into account the 90th percentile of requests (ruling out 10% outliers for long running requests)
- How many requests were at or under 1000ms?
Based on these responses and every article I've seen there is no way to do this with a single PromQL query.  This surprises me as this is such a common scenario.

Comment: Appreciate the responses but these seem to miss the point of what I'm after.  Both responses seem to suggest I want to alert when the percent of requests drops below 90%, which is not what I'm after.  

I want to evaluate only the 90th percentile of requests where duration was at or below 1s.  I want to exclude the upper 10% of calls that were long running anomalies to understand what the experience is like for 90% of customers.  The actual SLO objective will be something like 99.9%

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that I'm replying to an old thread but maybe it will be still helpful to someone.

I understand that you want to build an SLO which could be phrased as:

> 90th percentile of requests latency is lower than 1000ms 99.9% of the time over a week.

I added the *week* part as I haven't found over what period your SLO is considered.

I believe it can be solved by the following PromQL query:

```
avg_over_time(
  (histogram_quantile(
    0.9,
    sum by (le) (rate(MyMetric_Request_Duration_bucket{instance="foo"}[1h]))
  ) <bool 1)[7d:]
) * 100
```

The trick is that it calculates the `90th` percentile and then performs a binary quantization of the result. In other words, it creates a vector of `1`s and `0`s corresponding to when the target value is met and when it's not. Then, the `avg_over_time` function produces the ratio of good to all samples.

I faced a very similar problem. Based on my solution I wrote this article. I've put there a few remarks why in general it's better to avoid percentiles in SLO. You might find it interesting: https://mkaz.me/blog/2024/slo-formulas-implementation-in-promql-step-by-step#formula-for-latency-slo-with-percentiles

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Out of all the requests how many are getting served under 1000ms, to find that I would divide the total number of requests under 1000ms by the total number of requests.. In my gcp world, it translates to a query like this:

You are basically measuring your

```
(sum(rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_bucket{reporter="destination",namespace="abcxyz",le="1000"}[1m]))/sum(rate(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count{reporter="destination",namespace="abcxyz"}[1m])))*100
```

Once you have a graph setup with the above query in grafana, you can setup an alert on anything below 93 that way you are alerted even before your reach your SLO of 90%.

Comment: Thank you Isaiah!  
So is this the only way to do this with PromQL?  We use Sloth to create our create our recording and alerting rules, and I'm not sure we have the ability to make changes to the rules that Sloth spits out.  If there's no other way to do it then I guess we have no choice.

Comment: This is trivial to do with KQL or SQL and given it's such a common scenario I'm disappointed I can't do this with PromQL.  I guess PromQL has a long way to go.

Comment: How do you do this thing, but if there is not a bucket corresponding to your SLO?